# Problema con select2 en campos dinamicos wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, select2

Estoy usando select2 para poner un buscador interno e integrado a mis select los cuales facilita la búsqueda y selección de elementos en ellos..

uso las librerías

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/select2.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/select2.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selector').select2();
    });
});
</script>
```

y el el código a los campos select les adiciono la class selector y funciona perfecto...

**EL PROBLEMA Y MI CONSULTA**
Solo este atributo no aparece en los campos que se crean dinámicos ya que en mi formulario tengo una opción para adicionar campos y a estos el select2 no les funciona salen como select normales pues estos están dentro de un script que genera estos campos y ni poniéndole la clase a estos funciona... el juego de campos que aparece son los que estan dentro de  var fieldHTML2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField2 = 10; //
    var addButton2 = $('.add_button2'); //agrega
    var wrapper2 = $('.field_wrapper2'); //wrapper  
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is   
    $(addButton2).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField2){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper2).append(fieldHTML2); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper2).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
//------------------------------------------
 var fieldHTML2 = '<div id="destino2"><label>Operario de Saneamiento: </label><select name="operario[]" required class="campos selector" id="operario"><option value="">Seleccione:</option> <?php $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM operarios_nom WHERE estado='activo' AND municipio='$municcc' AND tipooperario='Saneamiento' OR municipio='$municcc' AND tipooperario='Dual' ORDER BY nombre ASC"); while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { echo '<option value="'.strtoupper ($valores[nombre]).'">'.strtoupper ($valores[nombre]).'</option>';}?></select> <label>Hora Inicio: </label>                  <input name="hora1_operario[]" type="text" class="hora1" autocomplete="off" id="hora1_operario" size="1"/><label> Hora Final: <input name="hora2_operario[]" type="text" class="hora2" autocomplete="off" id="hora2_operario" size="1"/></label> Novedad de Operario: <input name="novedad_operario[]" type="text" id="novedadoperario" size="30"/> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Borrar Operario de Saneamiento"><img src="remove-icon.png" width="20" height="20"/></a></div>'; 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){$(document).ready(function(){$('.selector').select2();});});
 </script>
```

Como hago para que estos campos invoquen o llamen igualmente el class que existe para que funcionan y actuen con el atributo select2.... ayuda por favor!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo logré agregando esta línea:

```
$('.selector').select2();
```

en el script.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField2 = 10; //
    var addButton2 = $('.add_button2'); //agrega
    var wrapper2 = $('.field_wrapper2'); //wrapper  
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton2).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField2){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper2).append(fieldHTML2); // Add field html
            /// POR FINNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
             $('.selector').select2();
        }
    });
    $(wrapper2).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
```